# Javascript function does not run on a deleteform

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I need to work on a small website in order to learn using symfony2.
I need to display a javascript's confirmbox when I click on a delete button. But the JS does not run.

Here is the code of the createDeleteForm.

```
  private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('etudiant_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete',
                                        'attr' =>array(
                                        'onclick' =>'confirmDelete()')))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

Here's the code of javascript function :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function confirmDelete()
    {
        var choix = confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cet enregistrement ?");
        if(choix == null)
            break;
    }
</script>
```

Any ideas ?

edit : The "break" is the problem ! 
Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

change  `'onclick' =>'confirmDelete()'` with this  'onClick' =>'confirmDelete()'

Comment: ckeck in your client side if you have the onClick attribute, then check debug if you have any javascript errors

Comment: firebug said "confirmDelete is not defined"

Comment: this the problem you re function is not recognized where did you put it in your file html, is there any other erros before  'onclick' =>'confirmDelete()'  error

Comment: after the 'body' part, does that help ?

Comment: I think that should just work, try to call your function somewhere else just to see if you re browser recognize it or not

Comment: Break was the problem !